# JavaScript split markdown first into headings and then into sentences

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a markdown text like the following first to parts with a heading and then to sentences.

```
# Heading
some text including multiple sentences...
## another heading
some text including multiple sentences....
## ...
```

Into :

```
# Heading
sent1 
-----
sent2
-----
....
----
## another heading
sent1
----
sent2
----
....
----
## ...
```

It's what I tried:

```
var HReg = new RegExp(/^(#{1,6}\s)(.*)/, 'gm');
var SentReg = new RegExp(/\b(\w\.\w\.)|([.?!])\s+(?=[A-Za-z])/, 'g');


var res1 = text.replace(HReg, function (m, g1, g2) {
    return g1 + g2 + "\r";
});

result = res1.replace(SentReg, function (m, g1, g2) {
    return g1 ? g1 : g2 + "\r"; // it's for ignoring abbreviations.
});

arr = result.split('\r');
```

But it separates some headings from their first sentence or include another heading to its previous sentence.

Comment: When regex is your hammer everything looks like a thumb. IMO you'd be better off using an actual Markdown parser which does all this work for you. That aside: you'd be better off going line by line and keeping track of your current header depth and processing each "section" until you're either up a level or down a level, making the whole thing recursive and fairly straightforward.

Comment: It seems `var res1 = text.replace(HReg, function (m, g1, g2) {
        return "\r" + g1 + g2;
    });` works.

Comment: When using the contructor `new RegExp`, the first argument is a string, not a regex, so `var HReg = new RegExp('^(#{1,6}\s)(.*)', 'gm');` or use `var HReg = /^(#{1,6}\s)(.*)/gm;`

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means the best option (a proper parser is recommended), but here is a Regex which will serve good enough as a POC:

```
var s = `# Heading
some text, including multiple sentences. some text including multiple sentences! some text including multiple sentences?
## another heading
some text including multiple sentences. some text including multiple sentences! some text including multiple sentences?
## ABC
some text including multiple sentences. some text including multiple sentences! some text including multiple sentences?
`;

var result = s.match(/(#+.*)|([^!?;.\n]+.)/g).map(v=>v.trim())

0: "# Heading"
1: "some text, including multiple sentences."
2: "some text including multiple sentences!"
3: "some text including multiple sentences?"
4: "## another heading"
5: "some text including multiple sentences."
6: "some text including multiple sentences!"
7: "some text including multiple sentences?"
8: "## ABC"
9: "some text including multiple sentences."
10: "some text including multiple sentences!"
11: "some text including multiple sentences?"
```

You can remove `;` from between `[ ]` if you want to include that as part of a sentence block. This of course does not protect you from anyone who decides not to use punctuation. ;)

Comment: my own solution for sentence segmentation take into account abbreviations! Moreover, I need to have each heading with its first sentence. Anyway, thanks, I may want to split them separately and your solution has an idea.